# Frechet differentiability, asymptotic normality

Tags: asymptotics, normal-distribution

I try to prove the asymptotic normality from the Frechet differentiability. Consider

$$T(G)-T(F)=L_{F}(G-F)+o\left(d_{\star}(G,F)\right)$$

and

$$L_{F}\left(F_{n}-F\right)=L_{F}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\delta_{x_{i}}-x\right)\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}L_{F}(\delta_{x_{i}}-F)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}T_{x_{i}}^{\prime}(F)$$

Then, after the simplification, I get

\begin{eqnarray*}
T(F_{n})-T(F) & = & L_{F}(F_{n}-F)+o\left(d_{\star}(F_{n},F)\right),\\
\sqrt{n}\left(T(F_{n})-T(F)\right) & = & \sqrt{n}\left[L_{F}(F_{n}-F)+o\left(d_{\star}(F_{n},F)\right)\right],\\
 & = & \sqrt{n}L_{F}(F_{n}-F)+\sqrt{n}o\left(d_{\star}(F_{n},F)\right),\\
 & = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}T_{x_{i}}^{\prime}(F)+\sqrt{n}o\left(d_{\star}(F_{n},F)\right),\\
 & = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}T_{x_{i}}^{\prime}(F)+o_{p}(1).
\end{eqnarray*}

However, from the last formula, I do not see the asymptotic normality. Could someone help me, how from the last formula the asymptotic normality can be proven?

Thanks for your help.